# How to use superclass constructor in Qt Creator?

Tags: inheritance, constructor, qt-creator, qt5

As you might know, classes in **Qt Creator** are part of the project as **class.h** and **class.cpp** files. Let's presume that we have two classes A (a.h, a.cpp) and B (b.h, b.cpp), and that B inherits A. How can I use the A's constructor when using B's constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A's constructor is automatically called when you construct a B.

If you need to pass parameters to A's constructor to have it work correctly explicitly call it in B's constructor:

```
B::B()
 :A(Blah)
{
}
```

This would be common when A is QObject and you want the ownership stuff to happen correctly, you'll pass in the parent pointer in B's constructor and pass that onto A's:

```
B::B(QObject* parent_)
 :A(parent_)
{
}
```

This is nothing to do with Qt and is a pure C++ concept.

Answer (score 1):

You would have the files:

**a.h**:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A
{
public:
    A();
};

#endif // A_H
```

**a.cpp**:

```
#include "a.h"
#include <QDebug>

A::A()
{
    qDebug() << "A()";
}
```

**b.h**:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

class B : public A
{
public:
    B();
};

#endif // B_H
```

**b.cpp**:

```
#include "b.h"
#include <QDebug>

B::B() : A()
{
    qDebug() << "B()";
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    B ob;

    return a.exec();
}
```

And it would print out:

```
A()
B()
```